# Best practices to build an alert system using ravendb

Tags: c#, ravendb

I want to build an alert system using ravendb.

Actually i store books as following :

```
public class Book
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Users can create some alerts which match book title and description.

an alert is defined like that :

```
public class Alert
{
    public string UserId{get;set;}
    public string Keywords{get;set;}
}
```

When a book is posted, or some edited an then match user alerts, i what to notify users (by email or something like that).

So, anyone has best practices in order to make an efficient alert system without looping through all alerts every time a book is posted or edited and execute the search query in order to get matching book ?

EDIT : I'm using Rhino.ESB in order to get notified when books are posted or edited, my question is not about how to get notified of books updates. But actually how to efficiently match books with alerts on thoses updates.

EDIT : StackOverFlow seems to use a subscription mechanism on tags to send user email with questions related to theses tags. A brief on this mechanism should be a beginning. Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoann,

You basically do a reversed search.

```
public void Handle(BookUpdated msg)
{
    var book = Session.Load<Book>(msg.BookId);
    var alerts = Session.Query<Alerts>()
        .Search(x=>x.Keywords, book.Description)
        .ToList();



    // alert for book


}
```

Note hat you will need to have paging properly, and consider what happens if you have a LOT of alerts for a book.

Comment: I thinked about doing this, but i was not sure it's the best way. About paging, i'll loop through all pages, i think it's not a problem. Thanks, i'll go this way.